# Bad output from keras LSTM generating a simple sequence

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to implement an LSTM layer with keras and test it on a very simple dataset.

Here is my code

```
X = np.load("X.npy")
y = np.load("y.npy")

trainX = X[:30, :, :]
testX = X[30:, :, :]
trainY = y[:30, :]
testY = y[30:, :]

lastDense = X.shape[2]

if(X.shape[2] == 1):
    lastDense = 1
    trainX = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
    testX = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))

in_out_neurons = trainX.shape[2]
hidden_neurons = 100

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(in_out_neurons, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(None, in_out_neurons)))
model.add(Dense(hidden_neurons))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(lastDense))
model.add(Activation("linear"))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")

model.fit(trainX, trainY, nb_epoch=700, batch_size=trainX.shape[0])

print 'train'
print trainX
print model.predict(trainX)

print 'test'
print testX
print model.predict(testX)
```

It does not display any errors, it runs and displays outputs.

The sequence I gave it is simply the numbers 1-39 in increasing order, where 1-31 is the training set and 32-39 is the testing set.

It is ordered in triplets, meaning a single training example would be `(1, 2, 3)` and I expect an output of `4`.

Here is the output for the training data

```
train
[[[  1.   2.   3.]]

 [[  2.   3.   4.]]

 [[  3.   4.   5.]]

 [[  4.   5.   6.]]

 [[  5.   6.   7.]]

 [[  6.   7.   8.]]

 [[  7.   8.   9.]]

 [[  8.   9.  10.]]

 [[  9.  10.  11.]]

 [[ 10.  11.  12.]]

 [[ 11.  12.  13.]]

 [[ 12.  13.  14.]]

 [[ 13.  14.  15.]]

 [[ 14.  15.  16.]]

 [[ 15.  16.  17.]]

 [[ 16.  17.  18.]]

 [[ 17.  18.  19.]]

 [[ 18.  19.  20.]]

 [[ 19.  20.  21.]]

 [[ 20.  21.  22.]]

 [[ 21.  22.  23.]]

 [[ 22.  23.  24.]]

 [[ 23.  24.  25.]]

 [[ 24.  25.  26.]]

 [[ 25.  26.  27.]]

 [[ 26.  27.  28.]]

 [[ 27.  28.  29.]]

 [[ 28.  29.  30.]]

 [[ 29.  30.  31.]]

 [[ 30.  31.  32.]]]
[[  4.09406757]
 [  5.05801105]
 [  5.98857021]
 [  6.88568211]
 [  7.78905582]
 [  8.71695137]
 [  9.67439938]
 [ 10.66011047]
 [ 11.66990376]
 [ 12.69835663]
 [ 13.73967934]
 [ 14.78820229]
 [ 15.83870316]
 [ 16.88658524]
 [ 17.92800713]
 [ 18.95988846]
 [ 19.97993088]
 [ 20.98649979]
 [ 21.97856903]
 [ 22.95560837]
 [ 23.91747856]
 [ 24.86432266]
 [ 25.79648972]
 [ 26.71446228]
 [ 27.61878586]
 [ 28.51003265]
 [ 29.3887558 ]
 [ 30.25547028]
 [ 31.11066628]
 [ 31.77085686]]
```

It's working reasonably well. You can see the first example is indeed [1, 2, 3] and it outputs 4.09. the next example is [2, 3, 4] and it outputs 5.05, that's good enough for me.

But in the testing set, I'm getting the same result for every example.

```
test
[[[ 31.  32.  33.]]

 [[ 32.  33.  34.]]

 [[ 33.  34.  35.]]

 [[ 34.  35.  36.]]

 [[ 35.  36.  37.]]

 [[ 36.  37.  38.]]

 [[ 37.  38.  39.]]]
[[ 31.81325912]
 [ 31.85035133]
 [ 31.88280106]
 [ 31.91120529]
 [ 31.93606949]
 [ 31.95784378]
 [ 31.97691345]]
```

Very bad results.
Am I overfitting? I am using dropout so I shouldn't be, but I don't know whats happening and how to fix it. Am I using keras lstm layer incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, count is a simple function that an LSTM can do perfectly.

- Shuffle the examples that the network do not learn the increments between batches.
- Add a validation set, another split maybe. Keras allows you to use validation_data take a look on it, maybe there is a point on the "nth" epoch that starts to over-fit so you can "[early stop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7LiT.png)" the learning.
- Reduce the number of neurons, count or sum is a really simple operation.
- If this does not work.. Increase the number of examples.. maybe 10k. Increasing the number of examples can avoid over-fitting.

Have fun playing!

Example:

```
X = []
for x in range(100):
    X.append([[x], [x+1], [x+2], [x+3]])
X = np.array(X)


np.random.shuffle(X)

trainX = X[:30, 0:-1, :]
testX = X[30:, 0:-1, :]

trainY = X[:30, -1, :]
testY = X[30:, -1, :]

lastDense = X.shape[2]

in_out_neurons = trainX.shape[1]
hidden_neurons = 100

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(in_out_neurons, return_sequences=False, input_shape=( in_out_neurons,1)))
model.add(Dense(hidden_neurons))
model.add(Dense(lastDense))
model.add(Activation("linear"))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam", lr=.1)

model.fit(trainX, trainY,validation_split=0.05, epochs=2000, batch_size=trainX.shape[0])

print ('train')
print (trainX)
print (model.predict(trainX))

print ('test')
print (testX)
print (model.predict(testX))
```

Comment: Neither of these things help. I think there might be a problem with the code. Do I need to maybe use a stateful machine?

Comment: np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1])) Keras expects the inputs as (batch_size, sequence_len, features) so your shape shoud be (X, 3, 1) like a char level charbot..

Comment: Oddly enough it didn't work when I did that. That's why I added the "if" part. And it only didn't work if the number of features in each example of 1. I mean didn't work as in - didn't run at all. Got an error.

Comment: because you should fix your input_shape as **input_shape=(3,)** or **input_shape=(3, 1)** depending on your data

Comment: Removed the reshaping, my data is now (10000, 3, 1) and input shape i've tried (3,1) and (3,). in (3,) i get an error "ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2" and when its (3, 1) I get the error "TypeError: Cannot convert Type TensorType(float32, 3D) (of Variable Subtensor{:int64:}.0) into Type TensorType(float32, (False, False, True)). You can try to manually convert Subtensor{:int64:}.0 into a TensorType(float32, (False, False, True))."

Comment: added working example.. try to change the learning rate and the epochs to more accurate results. Notice im using python 3.6 and Keras 2 with Tensorflow 1.0